# How to resolve this error “com.android.internal.policy.PolicyManager cannot be resolved to a type” in android

Tags: java, android

I am creating simple video player application which play video from URL and live stream.

I use the following code for player video. Everything is fine but I am unable to resolve the  problem of this line in below code:

> " com.android.internal.policy.PolicyManager mWindow=
>   PolicyManager.makeNewWindow(mContext); "

It shows the error message

> com.android.internal.policy.PolicyManager cannot be resolved to a type
>   in android

How to resolve this error?

```
 mWindow = PolicyManager.makeNewWindow(mContext);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. 
The `mWindow = PolicyManager.makeNewWindow(mContext);`
 returns [Window](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.2_r1/android/view/Window.java#Window) not

> com.android.internal.policy.PolicyManager

Comment: hi gmetax, problem is that PolicyManager not resolve